# How to manage concurrency in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application having Oracle 11G as database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, concurrency, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

My MVC 4 application is having Oracle 11G database as its backend. How can I handle concurrency here? I am quite new to Oracle. I know, in SQL Server, we can use timestamp column, but not sure how can we manage it in Oracle?

I will be having Entity Framework 5 as the ORM.

Any guidance on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks